# Session variable not being set if not in global scope

Tags: php, session

I am trying to make a login system using a series of methods and sessions. This is how it works:

1. User makes POST request via XHR to domain.com/api/login
2. Nginx does a rewrite to domain.com/api.php?request=url
3. File runs some validations, and if everything is good, it instantiates the target class and then uses `call_user_func_array` to call the target method with the newly instantiated object.
4. Method called is `UsersController->logIn`, this method runs some validations, and then calls `UsersModel::Condition` which in simplest terms selects the user and returns an object with the user's properties and a few methods.
5. Then, we run `$instanceOfUserRow->LogIn()`, which updates the `last_logged` column of that user and also instantiates the session doing `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $this->user_id`.

However, no matter what I try, it just will not set the session variable. I tried the following:

- Naming the variable different, from `user_id` to `identifier`, to `id_test`, etc.
- Instead of setting it in the `UserRow->LogIn` method, set it instead in the `UsersController->logIn` directly, which also didn't work
- Created a session variable in my framework's main file (Called `Init.php`) called `test`.
- This session variable was set successfully and behaved correctly, and the behavior was the same if I renamed it to `user_id`, which I thought was weird.
- Created a simple function that was declared right after the `session_start` in the `Init.php` file called `set_session` that simply took the name and value and set a session like this: `$_SESSION[$name] = $value;`. This also didn't work.

At this point I have no idea what to do, I did verify that the session was active using `session_status` before setting any new variable. Classes are loaded using a custom autoload. I am not sure if the culprit is either how many files we are layering through (From the original request being API/login, then rewriting to api.php, then UsersController.php, then UsersModel.php and then UserRow.php) or if it could be just the fact that it is being called via `call_user_func_array`.

Any help or leads would really help out. Thank you.

Comment: Did you call session_start() before assigning to your session?

Comment: Is the session on a different domain to where you need it?

Comment: Yes, like I said earlier in the post, I even made sure that the session was active by using `session_status` before setting the new variable. The domains are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out even though nearly everything was the same, I was querying the API using **HTTPS**, but the request was being made from a page that was not over TLS.

So requests were being made from `http://website.lan` to `https://website.lan/api` and that caused the session to change across requests.